# Simple definition for random polynomial $p:[0,1]\to[0,1]$

Tags: polynomials, definition

This should be a relatively simple problem but I'm looking for a clean definition for a random polynomial, $p$, that passes through the unit square. From suggestions from the comments, the order of the polynomial, $d$, can be whatever is needed and $p$ can be found by any means.

Now I've tried the obvious approach of just taking random points from the square and interpolating from them but sometimes, $p$ tends to jump out of the square.

Half of the time, it's fine and $p$ is within the bounds. The other half of the time, it isn't.

So how can I either mitigate this or redefine $p$ so that it fits these criteria?

That one's good.
[image: interpolation2]

That one's not.
[image: interpolation1]

Much obliged, Jam.

Comment: I suppose the size of $d$ is irrelevant (it may have to be quite large)? The one concern I have is what if one or more of  your $m$ randomly chosen points lie very close to the upper or lower boundaries of the square? (i.e., very close to the line segments $AD$ or $BC$)

Comment: Yup, $d$ is irrelevant. Just put it in there in case anyone wanted to ask. For the record, the polynomials in the figures are both cubics. Why do you think a point being in a corner would cause a problem though?

Comment: @Jam I think Nicholas's point is that $d$ would have to be unbounded in order for the polynomial to fit inside the square, for instance if you take a sequence of examples with one point at $(0,0)$ and another at $(\epsilon,1)$.  It seems unreasonable to make $d$ a parameter while also expecting randomness in the $m$ seed points.

Comment: @Jam I think you should make it clear what your goal is.  I doubt there's anything that fits all your stated requirements of 1) a simple definition, 2) interpolating through $m$ random points, 3) fitting inside the unit square, 4) a polynomial, 5) of degree $d$.  Which of these can actually be dropped to allow the others?

Comment: @ErickWong Hi Erick, thanks for your suggestions. I see what you mean about $d$ needing to be unbounded. I suppose I phrased the question slightly poorly; the interpolation wasn't a necessity for the polynomial, just a means I'd considered for generating it. And the parametrization of $d$ isn't too important either. In regards to what my goal is, with your suggestions, I'd say I'd just drop $(2)$ and $(5)$ so it's: a polynomial confined to the unit square with a clean definition.

Comment: I've edited the statement of the question accordingly.

Comment: @Jam Thanks, I've added an answer that isn't definitive but provides some suggestions that I hope you'll find helpful in your pursuit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how "well-distributed" you want your polynomials to be, here's two simple things that seem worth trying:

1) Every [Chebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) maps $[-1,1]$ to itself, so taking an arbitrary convex combination of them will always stay within the square $[-1,-1]^2$, which you can easily rescale to fit inside the unit square.  The basic Chebyshev polynomials have the nice property that they fit exactly inside the square, hitting the top and bottom edges a maximal number of times for their degree.

2) [Bernstein polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial) should behave better than Lagrange interpolants in terms of boundedness over the entire interval.  They will allow you to find a high-degree polynomial that stays within a bounded envelope of any given continuous curve that you draw in the square.  I believe that by convexity they should stay within the unit square if the original curve is within the unit square; if not you could always rescale by a small amount.

Comment: +1 for Bernstein polynomials (great info for future reference). I had only thought of Chebyshev polynomials, or Weierstrass's Theorem (which gives no insight on the actual construction), but Bernstein polynomials actually give you a constructive proof of Weierstrass's Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Though Erick Wong's provided a great solution, I'll post one I came up with, for posterity.

> Let $F_n(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\cos(ix+\phi_i)$ with $a_i$ in $[0,1]$ and $\phi_i$, in $\mathbb{R}$. Then, for all $x$, $\frac{F_n(x)+1}{2\sum a_i}$, will be in $[0,1]$ since $\cos$ is in $[-1,1]$. Lastly, define $p(x)$ as the Taylor Series for $\frac{F_n(x)+1}{2\sum{a_i}}$, at $x=\frac{1}{2}$, with a degree sufficiently high, such that $p$ stays in $[0,1]$.

It's not quite as clean as I'd hoped but works quite well and can probably be simplified. The idea came from a polynomial fitting a random Fourier Series, without terms in $\sin$ since they complicated things. The phase shifts were necessary since each $F_n$ was coming out of the $y$ axis at predictable points.

In the diagram below, I've shown, superimposed, about $20$ to $30$ degree $9$ polynomials, using this method, with $n=4$ and $\phi_i$ in $[-3,3]$. Clearly they all stay within the confines of the unit square, fill up the space quite well and are pretty random so I'd consider this method a success.

[image: random polynomials]

When we see what it looks like with about $100$ or so of $p$, it's clear that they cluster around $y=\frac{1}{2}$, which is to be expected, so the method doesn't provide polynomials with an equal chance of being at *every* point in the unit square but they're reasonably random nonetheless.

[image]